# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted] when doing a swap using pancakeswap router on bsc testnet

Tags: web3.py

I am unable to do a simple swap, a little help here will be very appreciated :

```
from web3 import Web3

# Binance Smart Chain Testnet node endpoint (e.g., Infura)
bsc_testnet_node_url = "https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc_testnet_node_url))

# Your wallet private key
private_key =  'private keys goes here'


# Address of the router contract on BSC testnet
router_address = "0x9a489505a00cE272eAa5e07Dba6491314CaE3796"

# Token addresses
token_in_address = "0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd"  # WBNB BSC testnet
token_out_address = "0x8d008B313C1d6C7fE2982F62d32Da7507cF43551"  # Cake2 (Pancakeswap token)

# Amount to swap (in the smallest unit, e.g., wei for Ether)
amount_in = 1000000000000000

# Path for the swap
path = [token_in_address, token_out_address]

# Nonce for the transaction
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count("0x88221Ba56f689e6b3d802454A0FfC6E936463635")

# Router ABI (You need to know the exact ABI)
router_abi=[router abi goes here(very long I just replaced it with this)]

swap_data = w3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=router_abi).encodeABI(
    fn_name='swapExactTokensForTokens',
    args=[amount_in, 0, path, "0x88221Ba56f689e6b3d802454A0FfC6E936463635"])
    #'swapExactTokensForTokens', [amount_in, 0, path, "0x88221Ba56f689e6b3d802454A0FfC6E936463635", deadline])

# Create the swap transaction
swap_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction({
    "from": "0x88221Ba56f689e6b3d802454A0FfC6E936463635",
    "gas": 100000,  # You might need to adjust the gas limit
    "gasPrice": 50000000000,  # Gas price in gwei (you can adjust this)
    "nonce": nonce,
    "to": router_address,
    "data": swap_data,
}, private_key)

# Send the transaction
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(swap_txn.rawTransaction)

print(f"Swap transaction sent: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/{tx_hash.hex()}")
```

I keep getting the error : https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x8bfafdf7fefe6e0aff53d985e7e1f5524e8ea248604892751d4ff4303a43760f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to executing the swap transaction, you need to set the allowance for the router contract to spend WBNB on your behalf.

Here's a quick Python code that shows there's `0` allowance for the router contract to spend WBNB on behalf of your account `0x88221Ba56f689e6b3d802454A0FfC6E936463635`:

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/'))

WBNB_contract_address = '0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd'

# Load ABI
with open('WBNB_ABI.json', 'r') as abi_definition:
    WBNB_ABI = json.load(abi_definition)

WBNB_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=WBNB_contract_address, abi=WBNB_ABI)

# Query allowance
owner_address = '0x88221Ba56f689e6b3d802454A0FfC6E936463635'
spender_address = '0x9a489505a00cE272eAa5e07Dba6491314CaE3796'
allowed_amount = WBNB_contract.functions.allowance(owner_address, spender_address).call()
print(f"The spender {spender_address} is allowed to spend {allowed_amount} tokens on behalf of {owner_address}")
```

Output:

```
The spender 0x9a489505a00cE272eAa5e07Dba6491314CaE3796 is allowed
to spend 0 tokens on behalf of 0x88221Ba56f689e6b3d802454A0FfC6E936463635
```

A super simple way (not recommended but just for this testnet) to set the allowance is:

1. Go to [WBNB Write contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd#writeContract) on bscscan.
2. Connect with `0x88221Ba56f689e6b3d802454A0FfC6E936463635`
3. In `guy (address)` set: `0x9a489505a00cE272eAa5e07Dba6491314CaE3796` (router)
4. In `wad (uint256)` set: `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935` (default max allowance, strongly not recommended in prod)
5. Send the tx.

As a side note, make sure you adjust your gas values as it fails with the ones in your code:

```
    "gas": 100000,  # You might need to adjust the gas limit
    "gasPrice": 50000000000,  # Gas price in gwei (you can adjust this)
```

You might want bigger `gas` and lower `gasPrice`.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining how to approve, very appreciated.
it's indeed what was missing, once I followed the steps to approve the transaction went trough.

Answer (score 0):

Your call revert because you or the source you transfer from, does might have a sufficient balance or the gas limit is to low.

```
function transferFrom(address src, address dst, uint wad)
    public
    returns (bool)
    {
        require(balanceOf[src] >= wad); // <<-- reverts here
...
```

This is what Tenderly reports, Notice how the call did not revert on the allowance but before it. This is why i pointed out your balance and not the approval. Your gas limit might be the cause to and you happened to run out of gas at this point.

```
{
  "[FUNCTION]": "transferFrom",
  "[OPCODE]": "REVERT",
  "[ERROR]": "execution reverted",
  "gas": {
    "gas_left": 0,
    "gas_used": 0,
    "total_gas_used": 100000
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried lowering the size of the transaction to an amount I am 100% sure I have in my wallet but it's not working. I think it's because I didn't approve the transaction maybe ?

Comment: Yes you should approve it as well.

Comment: I approved the transaction as explained by Ake above and it's working now, thank you so much!